# How to access my website without entering the FQDN, just the domain

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind

To access my website (just a testing page for now) I have to enter hostname.domainname.com. I would like instead of just entering the domain name (domain.com).

Do i have to configure BIND, do I need an other application or do I need to change the Domain Register (CloudFlare).

Currently on Ubuntu Server 18.04 Fully update!

Sorry for my bad english! 
And thank you!

Comment: If the domain is public, you need to set up an A record and a CNAME record. There's a lot of resource online about this. For example https://simpledns.com/kb/16/configure-web-site-for-access-with-and-without-the-www-domain-name-prefix

Comment: Are you running bind for your DNS now? If yes, show us your forward configuration files, particularly your SOA area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an entry to the `/etc/hosts` file

First get the ip adress with this:
`dig +short hostname.domainname.com`
Let's say the ip is `11.22.33.44`

Add a line to `/etc/hosts`

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
#
# Add a line like this <ip-adress><tabulation><hostname>:
11.22.33.44               domain.com
#
# Save file with <ctrl>+<o>, quit nano with <ctrl>+<x>
```

Comment: Wow that was fast thank you. I will try as soon as possible. Currently at work.

Comment: dig +short .... give some Cloudflare ip, should I turn off the proxy or just enter that ip adress.

Comment: you can use the cloudflare ip I guess